# Deserializar JSON C#

Tags: c#, json

Pregunta super simple, estoy recibiendo el siguiente JSON:

```
"{\"Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC\":{\"INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC\":{\"COD_INDICADORINTERNO\":\"318\",\"DES_FECHA\":\"2019-09-29T00:00:00-06:00\",\"NUM_VALOR\":\"583.88000000\"}}}"
```

lo logro usando esto:

```
var jsonConvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

como puedo almacenar el valor de `NUM_VALOR` en un `string`?

Comment: deberia estar dentro de jsonConvert.. te fijaste que contiene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si le das algo de formato usando por ejemplo

[jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print)

veras que queda algo como

```
{
  "Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC": {
    "INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC": {
      "COD_INDICADORINTERNO": "318",
      "DES_FECHA": "2019-09-29T00:00:00-06:00",
      "NUM_VALOR": "583.88000000"
    }
  }
}
```

entonces podras aplicar

[json to class](https://app.quicktype.io/)

para conseguir las `class c#` basado en el `json` de ejemplo

```
public partial class RootObject
{
    public DatosDeIngc011CatIndicadoreconomic DatosDeIngc011CatIndicadoreconomic { get; set; }
}

public partial class DatosDeIngc011CatIndicadoreconomic
{
    public Ingc011CatIndicadoreconomic Ingc011CatIndicadoreconomic { get; set; }
}

public partial class Ingc011CatIndicadoreconomic
{
    public long CodIndicadorinterno { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DesFecha { get; set; }
    public string NumValor { get; set; }
}
```

Si usas [json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) podras deserializar usando

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

asi puede deserializar tipado

Nota: Use `RootObject` porque no se que representa el json, pero puedes cambiarle el nombre a esa clase

Answer (score 1):

Puede utilizar `JObject.Parse` como asi:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

string json = "{\"Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC\":{\"INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC\":{\"COD_INDICADORINTERNO\":\"318\",\"DES_FECHA\":\"2019-09-29T00:00:00-06:00\",\"NUM_VALOR\":\"583.88000000\"}}}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
string numValor = o["Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC"]["INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC"]["NUM_VALOR"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo declarando la siguiente clase para deseralizar el json:

```
 public class Respuesta
{
    public INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC { get; set; }
}

public class INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC
{
    public string COD_INDICADORINTERNO { get; set; }
    public string DES_FECHA { get; set; }
    public string NUM_VALOR { get; set; }
}
```

Posteriormente acceder a deserializar de la siguiente manera:

```
 // Deserialización del Json de repsuesta
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var dTemplate = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                code = dTemplate.Deserialize<Respuesta>(json);
                string valor = code.Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC.NUMVALOR;
            }
```

La variable quedaría en el string valor.

Espero te sirva.